# Mapview V2 callout

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

In android I implemented the MapView V2 API and created a custom callout when a user taps the marker on the map. However i use the Title and text field of the marker for other purposes and because these field contain strings the default white callout appears when tapping a marker. I already tried the hideInfoWindow() method on creation and on the click event of the marker but its not working. Any ideas?

EDIT
Is there maybe a way to programatically deselect a marker? Like in iOS's Objectie-C marker.deselectAnnotation(). This method deselects a marker in the code.

Comment: mapView.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

marker.hideInfoWindow();

return false;
   }
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by returning true instead of false